# runing ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop, and Widows Vista already was installed on another partition. Now when I turn on the desktop it goes directly to windows. How could I make it ask which system should it run with?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to create a bootloader in which you can choose what operating system your computer should be booted in.